# How to connect php 7 with oracle 12c using oci8 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, php-7, oracle12c

I am using php 7 with Oracle 12c in ubuntu16.04.Want to connect php with Oracle database using oci8. When I type php - m|grep oci8 then it shows it is installed. But when I try to connect it shows "could not find driver". 
Many solutions are shown in windows but not in Linux. I can connect oracle using a username and password and fire query in oracle query console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the appropriate environment variables for Oracle e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set.  These need to be set separately for your webserver and your terminal shell.

For the Ubuntu webserver you will probably use the apache2 envvars file (It's /etc/sysconfig/httpd on RHEL systems).  There are tips are in the section 'Setting the Oracle Environment for PHP on Linux' on p77 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html